# Toolbar как убрать отсуп слева?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

С лева от значка навигации нужно полностью убрать отступ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В англоязычном stackoverflow проблема подымалась не раз, но решения я не нашел.
Единственное что "помогает" это игра с атрибутам  `android:paddingLeft` , при присваивании отрицательных значений отступ убирается, но в месте с ним "плывет" весь `toolbar`, и "Done" уходит влево тоже.

```
 private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView textToolbarMain;
private TextView textToolbarDone;
private ImageView backBtn;
private ConstraintLayout constraintLayoutToolbar;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choice_auth,container);

    toolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)myView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
```

Вот разметка:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme">
```

И вот:

```
 <style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">-30dp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"

    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp" />
```

Comment: Почему то мне это не помогало. Хоть какие значения dp ставлю  - содержимое toolbar на том же месте.

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, если вам надо убрать отступ слева в `Toolbar` то я сделал это с помощью вот этой строчки кода:

```
toolbar.setPadding(-25,0,0,0);
```

Для отступа слева ввел отрицательное значение.
Вот так получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит код добавления `Toolbar` во `Fragment`:

```
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choice_auth,container);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
    toolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)myView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    toolbar.setPadding(-25,0,0,0);//for tab otherwise give space in tab
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);

    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setTitle("My toolbar good boy!");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```